# Dress code violations

Tags: professionalism, dress-code

Customer service is most important in sales. We have teams of 23 people working on the floor and 1 receptionist who has dressed like she really trying to get some attention from one of the 23 men there: very short mini skirts and low cut tank tops that show 4 inches of cleavage (no exaggeration).

There are memos that HR have sent and all of them ignored by her. I have complained to upper MGT and they agree with me but do nothing about it.

I am losing respect for a company I have worked for many years as they let this go on and feel embarrassed to invite friends and family in to shop. I do not have any jealous issues, I am a good hard worker who wants to do well for myself and the company.  I focus on sales mostly, but she knows I cannot stand it when she slaps one of the guys on the behind, or takes selfies of herself right in customers view.

I do not wish for her to lose her job, although she does not work much in her 40 hours. I just want to feel comfortable at work. Isn't that harassment against me?  I feel like it is.  Everyone does respect me at work, I am just getting tired of the sly looks and rudeness to me.

She does know how I feel, because of the complaint to upper management. Should I stay or go?

Comment: sounds like she would be good for attracting customers, if of course, she actually looked good to go with the outfit. I worked at a bar once where patronage soared after they dressed all the barmaids in what you're describing.

Comment: No, not good at all. very poor taste pairing clothes and too tight for too much weight. The guys are not attracted, they are intimidated.

Comment: no one including upper management seem to mind, so there is not a lot you can do.

Comment: I understand that you feel uncomfortable, and I sympathize. However, you're also making a _much_ bigger deal out of this than it needs to be. All you have to do is ignore her and carry on with your day. Through her behavior and attire she is simply making a fool of herself. There's no need to get down to her level.

Answer (score 13):

From your description, this is entirely your problem.  How she presents herself has absolutely nothing to do with you.

If the bosses don't object, then by definition it is not a dress code violation for that role in that workplace.

Fix your attitude. Learn to ignore it.

Or find a workplace that conforms to your preconceptions.

Comment: in addition, it can and probably is backfiring on you to make your distaste known.

Comment: Agree. I can see the POV of the OP, but at the same time, it's management/upper management's job to decide violations. Also, if it is customer service...sex does sell. If it bothers you this much, perhaps you should seek a transfer to another branch or another employer.